# Scala working with Java libraries not specifying collections' type parameters

Tags: java, scala, generics

I am working with some old Java libraries that use collections not specifying type parameters (e.g. Eclipse draw2d) in Scala.

Suppose that you have a java class (that you cannot modify) like this:

```
// A.java
package com.example.test;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class A extends ArrayList {}  // not ArrayList<Object>, just ArrayList
```

If you want to work with class A in Java, you can do this:

```
// B.java
import com.example.test.A;

public class B {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    a.add(1);
  }
}
```

`javac B.java` succeed with some warnings:

```
Note: C.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

However, the identical thing with Scala is impossible:

```
// C.scala
import com.example.test.A

object C {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a = new A()
    a.add(1)
  }
}
```

`scalac C.scala` emit an error:

```
C.scala:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: E
    a.add(1)
          ^
```

How can I use this class in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you can do is:

```
val a = new A
val ls = a.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[Any]]
ls.add(1)
```

But again you will not be able to use other methods from `A`. I am still unsure on how you would be able to access `A` methods. The reference (in Change logs says):

> A raw type in Java such as ArrayList is translated to ArrayList[_],
>   which is a shorthand for ArrayList[T] forSome { type T }

So the scala compiler always takes it as `A extends ArrayList[E] forSome {type E}` and am unsure on how the type can be escaped (at compile time).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
// C.scala
import com.example.test.A
import java.util.ArrayList

object C {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a = new A()
    a.asInstanceOf[ArrayList[Any]].add(1)    // a.add(1)
    println(a.size())
  }
}
```

This code solved the problem!

But I still wonder how `ArrayList[Nothing] -> ArrayList[Any]` conversion is possible in Scala, while `Array` is invariant. Moreover, Scala accepts `ArrayList[Any] -> ArrayList[Nothing]` conversion too!